# Deleting a Jtable row from a custom model extending AbstractTableModel

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel, abstracttablemodel

I have a `JTable` that is using a custom model i have designed. This model is extending the `AbstractTableModel` as shown below. I have a button Delete that I would want when clicked will delete the **selected/highlighted row** Here is my table model:

```
public class ProductTableModel extends AbstractTableModel
{

    private final List<String> columnNames;
    private final List<Product> products;

    public ProductTableModel() {
        String[] header = new String[] {
            "Quantity",
            "Description",
            "Unity Price",
            "Total Price"
        };
        this.columnNames = Arrays.asList(header);
        this.products = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0: return Integer.class;
            case 1: return String.class;
            case 2: return Double.class;
            case 3: return Double.class;
                default: throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(columnIndex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        Product product = this.getProduct(rowIndex);
        switch (columnIndex) {
           case 0: return product.getProductQuantity();
            case 1: return product.getProductDescription();
            case 2: return product.getProductPrice();
            case 3: return product.getProductTotalAmount();
                default: throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(columnIndex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        if (columnIndex < 0 || columnIndex >= getColumnCount()) {
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(columnIndex);
        } else {
            Product product = this.getProduct(rowIndex);
            switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0: product.setProductQuantity((Integer)aValue); break;
                case 1: product.setProductDescription((String)aValue); break;
                case 2: product.setProductPrice((Double)aValue); break;
                case 3: product.setProductTotalAmount((Double)aValue); break;
            }
            fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return this.products.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return this.columnNames.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
        return this.columnNames.get(columnIndex);
    }

    public void setColumnNames(List<String> columnNames) {
        if (columnNames != null) {
            this.columnNames.clear();
            this.columnNames.addAll(columnNames);
            fireTableStructureChanged();
        }
    }

    public List<String> getColumnNames() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(this.columnNames);
    }

    public void addProducts(Product product) {
        int rowIndex = this.products.size();
        this.products.add(product);
        fireTableRowsInserted(rowIndex, rowIndex);
    }

    public void addProducts(List<Product> productList) {
        if (!productList.isEmpty()) {
            int firstRow = this.products.size();
            this.products.addAll(productList);
            int lastRow = this.products.size() - 1;
            fireTableRowsInserted(firstRow, lastRow);
        }
    }

    public void addEmptyRow() {
       products.add(new Product());
        this.fireTableRowsInserted(products.size()-1, products.size()-1);
    }

    public void insertProduct(Product product, int rowIndex) {
        this.products.add(rowIndex, product);
        fireTableRowsInserted(rowIndex, rowIndex);
    }

    public void deleteProduct(int rowIndex) {
        if (this.products.remove(this.products.get(rowIndex))) {
            fireTableRowsDeleted(rowIndex, rowIndex);
        }
    }

    public Product getProduct(int rowIndex) {
        return this.products.get(rowIndex);
    }

    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(this.products);
    }

    public void clearTableModelData() {
        if (!this.products.isEmpty()) {
            int lastRow = products.size() - 1;
            this.products.clear();
            fireTableRowsDeleted(0, lastRow);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a method for deleting a product from the model:

```
public void deleteProduct(int rowIndex) {
    if (this.products.remove(this.products.get(rowIndex))) {
        fireTableRowsDeleted(rowIndex, rowIndex);
    }
}
```

Here is the code that would be executed when the delete but is clicked:

```
delete.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
    if (e.getSource().equals(delete)) {
        int modelRowIndex = table.convertRowIndexToModel(table.getSelectedRow());
        ProductTableModel model=(ProductTableModel)table.getModel();
        model.deleteProduct(modelRowIndex);
    }
}
```

When I run this program it is showing the table as it is supposed to be. I add some rows in the table at run time using the `addEmptyRow()`in my `ProductTableModel`. When I highlight/select one row in the table and click the delete button, its showing me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(ArrayList.java:418)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:431)
at quotationTable.ProductTableModel.deleteProduct(ProductTableModel.java:119)
at quotationTable.Table$InteractiveTableModelListener.lambda$tableChanged$0(Table.java:152)
at quotationTable.Table$InteractiveTableModelListener$$Lambda$25/930643647.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Sorry for the big stack trace but one man advised me to put it in full.When I print the `table.getSelectedRow()`and `table.convertRowIndexToModel(table.getSelectedRow());` they are giving me -1.

How do we solve this and what could be the possible reasons?

Comment: It almost sounds like you have a shadow reference, ie- The instance of `table` isn't the one on the screen. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: @MadProgrammer  By simply mentioning the issue of  shadow referencing; you prompted me to revise my code. The result? - I was creating two references of  `myTable`. Your idea worked perfect. Allow me to say thanks for the idea, I was stuck.

Comment: When the obvious doesn't work, it's time to quit and become a gardener ;)

Comment: @Giovanrich everywhere (valid for another forums too where your questions are posted) is about to reducing a guessing about your goal, nor to construct code, testing unhandled and wrong code on answerers side, good effort equals good, excelent answers with relevant information in addition, for future --> for better help sooner post an SSCCE/MCVE, short, runnable, compilable with hardcoded value for model(s) in local variable

Answer (score 0):

probably in this line of code

```
this.products.remove(this.products.get(rowIndex)
```

rowIndex return null or zero value because check and debug this line my friend

Comment: *"When I print the table.getSelectedRow()and table.convertRowIndexToModel(table.getSelectedRow()); they are giving me -1"* - I would suggest the problem is some where else in the code, which hasn't been posted

Comment: That line is perfect, the problem is - I was having a shadow reference.

Answer (score 0):

The code I posted if fine and it works. The problem was due to a shadow reference -that is I was having two instances of my table.This answers why I was getting -1 when calling `getSelectedRow()`-the possible reason to my question why I was having this value yet I was adding rows to my table.In simple terms - I was adding rows to `myTable1OnTheScreen`and calling `deleteSelectedRow()`on `myTable2ThatHasNoRowsAddedToIt` hence, `getSelectedRow()`would return -1 because it was refering to `myTable2ThatHasNoRowsAddedToIt`.